# why is while causing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm testing out a selection sort but keep getting an infite loop.

Everything works fine when I have

```
while(arr.length > 3)
```

But when I make it any lower or change it to what it should be it causes an infinite loop in the code.

```
while(arr.length > 2)
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```js
    let arr = [55,21,33,11,25]
    let newArr = [];
    let smallest = 999999999;
    let index;
    
    function selectionSort() {
     while(arr.length > 2) {
      //loops through the numbers array
      for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
       // if the item is smaller, than pass it through
       if(arr[i] < smallest) {
        //change smallest to the arr[i]
        smallest = arr[i]
        index = i;
       }
      }
      //remove the smallest number from the arr
      arr.splice(index, 1)
      //push the smallest number to the new arr
      newArr.push(smallest)
     }
    }
    
    selectionSort()
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? Stepping through it and tracking the values of all your variables at each stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset `smallest` in each loop entries, otherwise once `11` is removed, other values will get compared against it and `index` never changes (`3`); and once `index` is greater than your array's length (at second iteration), your array is never spliced anymore.

```js
let arr = [55, 21, 33, 11, 25]
let newArr = [];
let index;

function selectionSort() {
  while (arr.length > 2) {
    let smallest = Infinity;
    //loops through the numbers array
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      // if the item is smaller, than pass it through
      if (arr[i] < smallest) {
        //change smallest to the arr[i]
        smallest = arr[i]
        index = i;
      }
    }
    //remove the smallest number from the arr
    arr.splice(index, 1)
    //push the smallest number to the new arr
    newArr.push(smallest)
  }
}

selectionSort()
console.log(newArr, arr)
```